# TBB concurrent_queue - accessing first element without popping it out

Tags: concurrency, tbb

I am using TBB concurrent_queue class. It meets my needs except that I need to access the first element before popping it out of the queue. As I understand from the document, one can't access first element or can't insert at the front like std:deque.

Any idea how to achieve this while maintaining concurrency as far as possible.

Comment: Right, you cannot do that with tbb::concurrent_queue. Reading an element in the queue is unsafe if the same element can be popped out of the queue by another thread. For understanding whether TBB could be of help for you, we'd need to learn more about the use case, e.g. how do you want to use these queue operations.

Comment: Could you use a mutex-locked `std::deque`? How big are the objects you want to access? Are they small or are they big objects on the heap? Are they being modified, or do you need locking to safely inspect them? If they aren't being modified, you could use a `std::deque<std::shared_ptr<const T>>`, then you could lock, copy the front element (the `std::shared_ptr<const T>`), and unlock.

Comment: @Ben we are talking about concurrency and not mutex

Comment: Well, they are related... How do you propose you safely read the front of the queue without locking? The instant you get a reference to the front of the queue, another thread could pop it, calling `~T` on it, resulting in undefined behavior. I believe that's the reason tbb's `concurrent_queue` is designed the way it is: that way nobody can peak inside it and so once you get access to an element, you know only you have access.

Comment: I think you could store `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<const T>>` in a queue with a different API, in which case you could safely peak at the front, but then once you read it and know what it is, you can’t use that to decide if you should pop the front. Unless, perhaps, it had an atomic `pop_if_equal(const T&)`, but I doubt that could be done lockfree; I think it would need a mutex.